# AWS S3 authentication error despite correct access key and secret

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy a json file to a table in Amazon Redshift. Code is like following

```
sql = """copy mydb.sales from 's3://example/user_x.json' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=AK;aws_secret_access_key=SK' format as json 'auto';"""
```

I am getting the AK and SK by

```
output1 = subprocess.check_output("curl -s http://example.com | grep ' \"xyz" : * ' | cut -f5 -d \" \" | cut -b2- | rev | cut -b3- | rev", shell=True)
AK = output1[:-1] #to remove the \n part from the subprocess output
```

The problem is I am getting following error:

```
 error:  S3ServiceException:The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.,Status 403,Error InvalidAccessKeyId
```

Now I was able to check the access and secret by a different method. They are exactly same as the output I have for AK or SK variable, as shown above.

Comment: at a guess AWS is getting an access key of exactly `AK`, you need to get the access key that's stored in your `AK` variable into the `sql` variable

Comment: Please tell me you are not downloading your access key and secret from a publicly accessible url.

Comment: No, I am not. just put the example.com as an example @cementblocks

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using an IAM role if possible. Create an IAM role with the necessary S3 permissions to read the files. Attach the IAM role to your redshift cluster. Then you can pass the role ARN in the credentials portion of the SQL statement

```
  COPY table FROM s3path CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=iam role arn here'
```

The trust policy for the role should be like this

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then in the Redshift console select your cluster and click Manage IAM roles. Then add select your IAM role.

Comment: Actually I tried this. I am getting error: user is not authorized to assume IAM Role. I am trying to check if my iam role has permissions as you said.

Comment: Check the trust policy and you also have to attach it to the cluster.

Comment: It comes down to trust policy as far as I could have verified. No issues with s3 permission.